# Regex first string between characters

Tags: python, regex

I have this string

```
_text = 'ITEM|6945541514535242|2|'
```

and how can I retrieve this string `'6945541514535242'` with regex?

`'6945541514535242'` and `'2'` are between `'|'`, but I want only get the first one.

Comment: post ur attempt? what's wrong with split?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use a regex instead of `split`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `\|(\d+)\|` and `re.search` to get only the first match, if any.

```
>>> _text = 'ITEM|6945541514535242|2|'
>>> re.search(r'\|(\d+)\|', _text).group(1)
'6945541514535242'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can be any text you will need to do an 'non-greedy' search:

```
>>> _text = 'ITEM|abcd6945541514535242|2|'
>>> re.search(r'\|(.*?)\|', _text).group(1) 
'abdc6945541514535242'
```

the ? makes it non-greedy so it matches as little as possible